# Problemas para acessar conteúdo da array

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de saber se algum de voces podem eme ajudar. Estou tentando ler o objeto da array em questao e nao estou conseguindo imprimir na tela, tanto com for quanto forach. se alguem puder me ajudar serei muito grato. segue o código:
P.S: gostaria de imprimir o [name] e o [email].

```
Iugu_SearchResult Object
(
    [_totalResults:protected] => 16
    [_results:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Iugu_Customer Object
                (
                    [_attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 123455554545455453
                            [email] => a@graficaeditora.com.br
                            [name] => Pré Impressão
                            [notes] => 3
                            [created_at] => 2018-08-09T09:07:24-03:00
                            [updated_at] => 2018-08-09T09:07:24-03:00
                            [cc_emails] => 
                            [cpf_cnpj] => 123454545435
                            [zip_code] => 17213000
                            [number] => 171
                            [complement] => casa
                            [default_payment_method_id] => 
                            [proxy_payments_from_customer_id] => 
                            [city] => Jaú
                            [state] => SP
                            [district] => Chácara Santo Antonio
                            [street] => Rua Antônio Carlos Nunes Takeda
                            [custom_variables] => Array
                                (
                                )

                    )

                [_unsavedAttributes:protected] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )
```

Comment: Ola @Leandro, Bem vindo ao SOpt, Falta algumas informações em sua pergunta, por exemplo: Qual linguagem você esta usando? *(Me parece ser php)* -- Você também poderia colocar o código que você tentou isso ajuda a comunidade te explicar onde esta o erro etc.. -- Vale apena você dar uma olhada no nosso [Tour]  =D

Comment: Ola Icado. Realmente esqueci de colocar a linguagem...É PHP. Na verdade isso é o resultado de uma funcao para gerar um boleto, segue a funcao:                                                    */
function geraBoleto($customer_id, $ddd, $telefone, $itens)
{
    $cliente = Iugu_Customer::fetch($customer_id);
    
   //echo "<pre>";
     //print_r($cliente);
   //echo  "</pre>";
 
}